# Styling Rails button link helpers with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Rails helpers to generate buttons and I'm trying to style the buttons with Twitter bootstrap styles for buttons.  I've added classes with the `:html` option. The page isn't breaking but the styles aren't showing up.

```
<%= button_to('Sign Up', new_user_registration_path, :html => {:class => 'btn.btn-large.btn-primary'})  %>
<%= button_to "Sign Up", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), :html => {:class => 'btn.btn-large.btn-primary'} %>
```

This is page source for the facebook button

```
<form action="/users/sign_up" class="button_to" method="post"><div><input html="{:class=&gt;&quot;btn.btn-large.btn-primary&quot;}" type="submit" value="Sign Up" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="QIvZqd9BRV8TMspMvckAUjhC68nm3NTyQCxVRHFA4PE=" /></div></form>
<form action="/users/auth/facebook" class="button_to" method="post"><div><input html="{:class=&gt;&quot;btn.btn-large.btn-primary&quot;}" type="submit" value="Sign Up" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="QIvZqd9BRV8TMspMvckAUjhC68nm3NTyQCxVRHFA4PE=" /></div></form>
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need `:class => "foo"` to set the class of the button, instead of `:html => { :class => "foo" }`.  So it should look like this:

```
<%= button_to('Sign Up', new_user_registration_path, :class => 'btn btn-large btn-primary')  %>
```

This will generate your large primary button.

Comment: I've updated the OP with an image showing how the class is attached to the input element. Any clues?

Comment: it needs spaces between the classes :class => 'btn btn-large btn-success' It works like this.

Comment: Twitter bootstrap uses spaces not dots. I have submitted an edit for the original post but it will need to be approved first.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer got close to a fix for me but needed to change the `button_to` to a `link_to`. Also got rid of the rocket... `=>`

```
<%= button_to('Sign Up', new_user_registration_path, class: 'btn btn-large btn-primary')  %>
```

Comment: I mean, the hash rocket should still work, it's just a syntax thing. But no idea what you mean by changing `button_to` to `link_to` since your snippet doesn't even have `link_to`